# where can i find a list of hex color codes to use in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, turtle-graphics

i am doing a small practice project using the turtle graphics module. i have created 8 turtles and want to change their color randomly. i was thinking of using the random module to make a random choice for a color. but for that, i would need a list of the hex codes of colors in string format. where can i find such a list? or if there is a library which has such a list, that would work too.

```
import turtle
import random

p1 = turtle.Turtle()
p2 = turtle.Turtle()
p3 = turtle.Turtle()
p4 = turtle.Turtle()
p5 = turtle.Turtle()
p6 = turtle.Turtle()
p7 = turtle.Turtle()
p8 = turtle.Turtle()
players = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8]

colors = []  # need a list of hex codes of colors

for player in players:
    player.shape('turtle')
    player.color(random.choice(colors))
    player.pu()
    player.goto(-225, 180 - 27*players.index(player))


while True:
    for _ in players:
        _.forward(random.randint(1, 10))


turtle.done()
```

i have copied the relevant part of my code here. how can i find a list of colors which the turtle library recognizes?

Comment: What do you mean, a list of hex codes? Why not generate them?

Comment: i mean a list like colors = ['#000000', '#FFFFFF', ...]
how does one generate it?

Comment: You do know those are just groups of three numbers from 0-255, right? Why in the world would you need a module or library to tell you those numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use colors from `matplotlib`:

```
list(matplotlib.colors.cnames.values())
```